# Error while inserting value in datetime column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert a record (from java code) in table but I'm getting "ERROR 1292 (22007)". The timestamp column is of type "datetime"
Following is my query

```
insert into Alert(name,timestamp,location,message) values ("aaa", "2013-04-25 5:47:3PM","XYZ", "bla bla bla");
```

Error

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: "2013-04-25 5:47:3PM" for column 'Timestamp' at row 1
```

Comment: can you show your java code? the format of date should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: The insert query mentioned is extracted from the logs. Also i tried to manually run this insert query in sql editor and got the same exception.

Comment: because the problem is on this part `5:47:3PM` dates cannot contain `AM/PM`.

Comment: hmm..got it...date format is problem...thx JW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `timestamp` value in your query to `2013-04-24 17:47:03`. The format for a `datetime` column must be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a 24-hour clock and get rid of the AM/PM. This will insert the same time you're attempting to insert in your question:

```
insert into Alert(name,timestamp,location,message)
  values ("aaa", '2013-04-25 17:47:3',"XYZ", "bla bla bla");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datetime formatting is wrong. Try:

```
2013-04-25 05:47:03
```

It's because `datetime` is based on a 24H format.

Here is the documentation about date formats in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html